# Current linux compatibilty with sim slot/4G LTE notebooks

Tags: linux, modem, mobile, lte

I'm thinking about a new notebook with sim card slot and I've found many products. However, is linux(not any specific distro) that far, that it works right out of the box? From my experience, I was worried that not and some simple googling just showed people having problems with it at the classical no real answer threads.

Even if it doesn't work out of the box, please try to provide some instructions for the community as googling them doesn't really help.

EDIT: It seems to be more of a distro specific question. I didn't pick any yet so some suggestions on distro with the least problems would be appreciated.

EDIT: It seems for Ubuntu it might work out of the box, but with real experience only from usb modems. I've found a question https://askubuntu.com/questions/104703/laptop-sim-card-slot-not-recognized where it seems it doesn't work for built-in slot, however it might be because the sim slot was just a dummy one.
Anyone actually used it with build-in slot?

Comment: It generally depends on Linux distro you want to use. So instructions should be distro family specific.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Would u mind providing info about a distro with the least problems with it, or the distro you have experience with?

Comment: Ok, as of Ubuntu it should work out of the box in most occasions (at least USB modems work this way). Arch Linux would probably require some configuration writing but it's not a big deal as Arch Linux Wiki usually holds all the necessary information.